# Is there a standard mortgage model available?

Tags: mbs

Is there a standard model (or way of modelling) different types of mortgages and different interest rates to find the optimal mortgage structure for home loans?

e.g. a loan of $800k structure across 20, 25 or 30 years at varying interest rates

Comment: There are plenty of mortgage calculators online (and formulas for spreadsheets), but I'm guessing you're asking something different?

Comment: Ideally I'm interested in something that can evaluate multiple scenarios and structures to determine what the best outcome is. I.e Fix for 1 year float for the rest vs fix for 1 and 3 years then float

Comment: If you have a tree (example http://www.expertsmind.com/CMSImages/355_binomial%20interest%20rate%20tree1.png) of future interest rate scenarios (subjective or constructed from an interest rate model) then you can compare the various structures.

Comment: I think the real difficulty here would be in predicting future rates. Do you have some way of modelling this that you feel is reasonably accurate?